# What’s the equivalent of turning the Digital Crown on the Apple vision pro headset simulator?

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator, visionos

In the demos of Apple Vision Pro, they show that you can manually switch between VR and pass-through-video-AR by rotating a Digital Crown on the headset. The simulator has a simulated series of environments but I don't see documentation on how to activate that control like the simulators do for home and side buttons on iPhone and iPad hardware.

What’s the equivalent of this action in the Apple Vision Pro headset simulator?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732458

Comment: Thanks! you should turn this into an answer!

Comment: if @nohillside doesn't answer - go ahead and self answer this. It could help others find the answer and avoid reading the whole thread of the developer forum.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the Simulator launched and an app that supports immersion, you can go to `I/O > Set Immersion To` and pick between 30%, 50%, and 100%.

Alternatively, you can run in an XCTest environment and use `XCUIDevice.rotateDigitalCrown(delta:)`

```
/*!
 * Rotate the digital crown by a specified amount.
 *
 * @param rotationalDelta
 * The amount by which to rotate the digital crown. A value of 1.0 represents one full rotation.
 * The value’s sign indicates the rotation’s direction, but the sign is adjusted based on the crown’s orientation.
 * Positive values always indicate an upward scrolling gesture, while negative numbers indicate a downward scrolling gesture.
 *
 */
- (void)rotateDigitalCrownByDelta:(CGFloat)rotationalDelta;
```